# New rewrite rules in subdirectory with htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim-3

I'm struggling with configuring the rewrite rules in the .htaccess files.
I'd like to run a *Slim PHP App* inside my Wordpress folder, so I can reuse the SSL certificate for my API.
The Slim App is running inside the /api folder, so it can be accessed by calling `https://www.example.com/api`.

This works well, but if I open an API endpoint like  **`example.com/api/timesheet`** the page is redirected to the **404 error** Wordpress page.

What I did so far:
I excluded the `api directory` in the `.htaccess` file inside the Wordpress root directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(api|api/.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on           
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And added these new Slim default rules in the `.htaccess` file inside the `api directory`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added after a lot of try and error `RewriteBase   /api` to the `.htaccess` file in the api directory to get it working properly.

The final .htaccess in `/api` now looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```