# Wordpress Protect Subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, directory, http-status-code-404, password-protection

I have a site which is in wordpress, there is one folder within root of  that, Which is built in static php.

When i am trying to protect that site with .htaccess it conflicts with root .htaccess of wordpress.

I have placed the protection htaccess within the folder

this is what i put in webmaster directory .htaccess file but it goes 404

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
AuthType Basic
AuthName "welvo maker"
AuthUserFile "/home/welvo/.htpasswds/public_html/webmaster/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello you can protect subfolder directory using .htaccess by adding below line

RewriteBase   /subfolderdirectoryname 

As well as you can see reference link which will help you to understand better.
```

[New rewrite rules in subdirectory with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732197/new-rewrite-rules-in-subdirectory-with-htaccess)